# What's the error in this code, i tried it not able to solve the problem?

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, node-modules

```
const server =http.createServer((req,res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200,{'Content-type':'text/plain'});
    res.end("hello world");
});
server.listen(200,'127.0.0.1',()=>{
  console.log("Listening on port 80");
});
```

kindly help with this code,dont know whats the error?

Comment: `http` is not defined add  `const http = require('http');`

Answer (score 0):

You have to import http from http module at the top. Make sure that you are sending the port number as the first argument inside `server.listen()`.

```
const http = require('http')
const PORT = 3000
const server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end("hello world");
});
server.listen(PORT, '127.0.0.1', ()=>{
    console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

Your server will run on `127.0.0.1:3000` or `localhost:3000`.